# Stopping an IntentService from an activity

Tags: android, intentservice

I have an `IntentSerivce` that runs in the background sometimes and it can be quite a long running process in certain instances. I give an option for the user to quit the application which basically just stops and polling and ignores any `GCM` push notifications. But if a push notification came in and the `IntentService` is taking a while to finish doing what it has to (gets information from a server and sends a notification to the user if needed, like a new message arrived or something).

Here is the problem, if the user elects to "Quit" the app while the `intentservice` is still running they will still get the notification which I do not want. I know that there is the `stopSelf()` method for the service but I need to stop it in an activity when I know the user "Quit" the application via a menu button. Sending another `intent` to the service does not work since the intents get queued up and calling `context.stopService(intent);` in my activity does not work either so how else can I stop it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing an IntentService to stop immediately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258083/forcing-an-intentservice-to-stop-immediately)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you passing a new `Intent` into `stopService(Intent)` or the original one used in `startService(Intent)`. Passing the original Intent should stop the service.

Failing that you could use a `Handler` to pass the service a `Message`. Have the `IntentService` implement the `Handler.Callback` interface and create a new `Handler(Handler.Callback)` in your `Activity`, passing your `IntentService` as callback. Then implement the `onHandleMessage()` in your IntentService to call `stopSelf()` and have your `Activity` pass a message to it when you want it to stop.

Comment: Where do you get from the service instance (I mean the Handler.Callback instance) when in the Activity started from the notification ?

Answer (score 3):

Below code is perfectly working fine for me to stop IntentService from Activity:

```
stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyIntentService.class));
```