# How to stop Intent Service in middle of my program?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice

Calling `stopService(Intent)` does not work, even though I am pressing `mStopButton`.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyReceiver myReceiver = new MyReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("Start"));

        Button mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyIntentService.class);
                startService(intent);
            }
        });

        Button mStopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        mStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyIntentService.class);
                intent.setAction("stop");
                stopService(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int res = intent.getIntExtra("count", -1);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Count is " + res,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyIntentService**

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            for (int i=0; i<=100; i++){
                Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                intent1.setAction("Start");
                intent1.putExtra("count",i);
                sendBroadcast(intent1);
                Log.v("abc",""+i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I stop the `IntentService`?

Comment: By the time you click the button, the service will have stopped itself. Your `onHandleIntent()` should complete in a few dozen milliseconds.

Comment: Cant I stop in middle ? Like after 10 or 20 counts?

Comment: Again, the work that you are doing in this service will take almost no time. Feel free to explain how you intend to even *find out* that "10 or 20 counts" have passed, let alone react in time to stop the service before it completes the remaining 80 or 90 counts.

Comment: you can try using a broadcastReceiver with the intentService. (send your Start/stop command as an Extra) see http://android-er.blogspot.sg/2016/05/example-of-intentservice-and.html. I use something similar to Start a radio service, and interrupt (pause/stop) that service.

Comment: I have edited my program, i put Thread.sleep(3000); I run the program, but not stopping in middle. Why? Why cant it stop even with Thread.sleep(3000)?

Comment: you may want to consider this too http://stackoverflow.com/a/22967394/908821. also, like what commonsWare said. increase your max i by at least a million times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant stop your `IntentService` that way. `IntentService` is stopped itself automatically.

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

You can define a `boolean isStop` value in your `IntentService` and change the value when `stop service` button is clicked. You have to check the boolean in the `for` loop like:

```
 // when click button
 YourIntentService.isStop = true;    
 // in for loop 
 for (int i=0; i<=100; i++){
            if(isStop) break;
            Intent intent1 = new Intent();
            intent1.setAction("Start");
            intent1.putExtra("count",i);
            sendBroadcast(intent1);
            Log.v("abc",""+i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

For best pratice, you should use `LocalBroadCastReceiver` instead of static boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

Intent service stops by itself when work is done you don't need to explicitly stop it.

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to stop in middle of my count, lets say somewhere 50 counts in my program, then what should i do?

Comment: to do that you can do what Kingfisher Phuoc suggested.