# How to cancel a JobIntentService

Tags: android, android-support-library

How can I cancel a [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html)? I see no methods to do so in the docs, apart maybe from the `JobSheduler` API and the `Context#stopService(...)` method, which I'm unsure if it's the right way.

Comment: Prior to Android 8.0, `JobIntentService` is implemented as an `IntentService`. While you could use `stopService()` to destroy an `IntentService`, this may not have an effect on the background thread used for `onHandleIntent()` (I have never tried this).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`JobIntentService` is only bringing `IntentService` to Android 8+ that is more strict about background services. It runs like old `IntentService`s on devices with older versions of Android.

**`IntentService` has never been designed to be cancelled**, hence the lack of any API to cancel a `JobIntentService`.

Therefore, **`JobIntenService` should only be used for work that don't need to be cancelled.** Note that `JobIntentService` can still be used for work that can *fail*, and consequently, be aborted.

Work that can be cancelled should be executed in either:

- An `Activity` (or its `ViewModel`) for short duration work
- A JobService (using Firebase Job Dispatcher or Job Scheduler if minSdk is 21)
- A custom foreground service

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Android 8.0, `JobIntentService` is implemented as an `IntentService`.  `IntentService` does not stop or take any other requests through some intent action until its `onHandleIntent` method completes the previous request.
`stopService`() won't be called until the task is finished.And it's called automatically when it is. That's a feature of `IntentService` But a similar question was already answered here referring to `IntentServices`, hope it helps.

[answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258083/how-to-force-an-intentservice-to-stop-immediately-with-a-cancel-button-from-an-a)

also check out [android developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html)