# Activity and JobIntentService Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-lifecycle

I am running a `JobIntentService` to perform a task in background. The reason for using `JobIntentService` is that so that the user can minimize the screen while the operation is happening and even if the Android OS destroys the activity the `JobIntentService` will still keep running and if the user comes back he can be updated with the results.

But I have a case in which suppose the user himself closes the app then I want to stop the `JobIntentService` also.

Is there any way to notify the `JobIntentService` when the user himself closes the app.

Any Help will be really appreciated.

**EDIT: I tries using `onTaskRemoved` by that is of no use aw my Test device does not call it(I am sure many other device would not be calling it either). Also The service is automatically stopped when the app is removed from the recent list but is then again restarted when the app is opened again which is what I don't want.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel a JobIntentService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922178/how-to-cancel-a-jobintentservice)

Comment: what do you mean by "the user closes the app"? How does the user "close the app"?

Comment: @DavidWasser Removing it from the recent list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that your `Service` is killed when the user swipes the task from the recent tasks list is that Android just kills the OS process hosting the application when the user swipes the task from the recent tasks list. Android will then restart any `Service` that was running in the OS process that it has just killed.

The behaviour of this has changed over time and is different on different version of Android and also some manufacturers have their own custom ROMs where they implement this in different ways.

There is nothing you can do that will ensure that your `Service` will not get killed and restarted by Android. You can try this, which may help:

Put your `Service` in a separate OS process. To do this add `android:process=":remote"` to the `<service>` tag in the manifest. On some versions of Android, swiping the task from the list of recent tasks only kills the OS process hosting the activities. This may prevent Android from killing your `Service` in this case.

You also say that `onTaskRemoved()` is not called and that your `Service` is not automatically restarted after Android kills it. This happens on some devices where the manufacturer is trying to aggressively save battery power. This is common on Chinese devices (Xiaomi, ZTE, etc.) and some LG, Huawei and Lenovo devices also show this behaviour. On these devices there is a list of applications that are allowed to run in the background (also known as "protected" apps). You must manually add your app to this list on these devices (or tell your users that they need to manually add your app to the list). If your app is in the list of "protected apps" or "apps allowed to run in the background", then Android might now kill off your `Service` if the user swipes the task from the list of recent tasks, or if it does kill it, it should call `onTaskRemoved()` and it should also automatically restart the `Service` immediately.

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer. But is there any way to assure that the `JobIntentService` is 100% killed when the user swipes the app from recent list? As the I want to stop the long running operation when the App is swiped from the recent list.

Comment: Sure. Just set `android:stopWithTask="true"` in the manifest. Then Android will always kill the `Service` when the user swipes the task from the list of recent tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have accepted but it say s cannot award bounty before 4hrs. But will surely do it after 4hrs. Thanks