# Android - Cancel JobIntent service when activity closes

Tags: android, kotlin, service

I will be starting my service to download data from server. I did this using `JobIntentService` but my problem is when i closed my activity i need to stop the service on Destroy, using that UNIQUE ID. is there is any other option to cancel the running `JobIntentService` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel a JobIntentService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922178/how-to-cancel-a-jobintentservice)

Comment: JobIntentService is not intended for such use unless you do some hacky workarounds with static variables. Better just use service with binding.