# How to cancel service from BroadcastReceiver API 26+

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I'd like to cancel my service on the user action (i.e a cancel button on the notification)
It's working on API < 26, but not on 26+. I'm looking for help to fix this if possible.

Here is my code:

**Activity**

```java
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("fileTitle", myFile.name);
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
```

**My Service (JobIntentService)**

```java
@Override
 public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        createNotificationChannel();

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        closeIntent .setAction("cancel_button")
                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND | Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);
        PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, closeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

       nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
                        .setTicker("")
                        .setContentTitle(FILE_TITLE)
                        .setContentText("Download starting")
                        .setProgress(100,0,false)
                        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel,"Cancel", actionIntent);
}

 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(isPostorEqualOS(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)){
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, nBuilder.build());
            enqueueWork(this, intent);
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

**My Receiver**

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if("cancel_button".equals(action)){
            Intent stopService = new Intent(context, DownloadService.class);
            boolean stop = context.stopService(stopService);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I mean that I see the boolean from my Receiver being called and returning true, but the service isn't going into `onDestroy` method

Comment: How exactly do you know your Service is created & running at the moment you press the button? Your foreground notification is showing, I assume? And, of course, you have not bound to the service?

Comment: I've used this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921190/6074224 to help me figure out, I've called the function after my `context.stopService(stopService)`

Comment: But obviously, the foreground notification is showing, right? And it continues showing after the `stopService()` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `JobIntentService` aren't designed to be cancel.

For more info:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47159305/6074224

I changed my service to `IntentService` instead and it's working.